# Failed to open PHPexcel.php

Tags: php, excel

this is my code.

```
<?php

    require_once '../lib/PHPExcel.php';

        $tmp_name = "dlwholesale_datafeed_aug_2018.xlsx";
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        echo "<table>";
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
             echo "<tr><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

But when i run it, something does not work good. Please can you help me solving this problem? I have this error?

> Warning:
>   require(E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib\PHPExcel.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php'
>   (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib\PHPExcel.php on line 5

I solved this, but i have another error now:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: tmpfname in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\scrapes\dlwholesaleX.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open  for reading! File does not exist. in E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(281): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007-&gt;canRead(NULL)
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\scrapes\dlwholesaleX.php(6): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile(NULL)
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php</b> on line <b>73</b><br />
```

Comment: does the path E:\xampp\htdocs\suppliers\dlwholesale\lib/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php exist on your computer?

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie this path is wrong.. it can not exist...  See here: **\...\.../.../** ------doki: have you read the error message?

Comment: I solved that, but know I have another error

Comment: Edit your question with your new error.

Comment: I did that already

Comment: can you help me>